# Do I need google-apis-explorer for Vision?

Tags: google-apis-explorer

I'm following the [OCR Tutorial](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/tutorials/ocr) so of course calling GC's API, and I noticed bottom of OCR home page mentions API Explorer. What is this "Explorer", do I need it for Vision?

Comment: You'll need to add some more information about what this "OCR Tutorial" is. Furthermore, searching for "API Explorer" gives me a link to Google's API Explorer, so decide for yourself whether you need it or not.

Comment: @KenY-N I'm totally new to GC. Followed what you said landed into https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/ , is it what it is, if so it does not answer at all.  Imagine if someone is completely new to GC, would it be confusing for so many new stuffs. It will be great if some experts can leave a few lines explaining and this is what SO is about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What the Explorer is is just a testbed for all the Google APIs so you can test the APIs in isolation or "Try Before You Buy" to see what functions are available. For instance, [this page](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/vision/v1/vision.images.annotate)  allows you to form a query for OCR and see what responses should look like. You don't need this tool, but it might be useful for debugging.

As an example, given [this random source image](https://4.bp.blogspot.com/-qKvpJ8AIPK4/WWj2GlarPSI/AAAAAAAAZGQ/vIdT3n4KXwEYv-tuzwGKRGbl1F5ij945ACLcBGAs/s1600/docs-textbox-postpic.png), [click this link to Google Explorer](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/vision/v1/vision.images.annotate?fields=responses&_h=2&resource=%257B%250A++%2522requests%2522%253A+%250A++%255B%250A++++%257B%250A++++++%2522image%2522%253A+%250A++++++%257B%250A++++++++%2522source%2522%253A+%250A++++++++%257B%250A++++++++++%2522imageUri%2522%253A+%2522https%253A%252F%252F4.bp.blogspot.com%252F-qKvpJ8AIPK4%252FWWj2GlarPSI%252FAAAAAAAAZGQ%252FvIdT3n4KXwEYv-tuzwGKRGbl1F5ij945ACLcBGAs%252Fs1600%252Fdocs-textbox-postpic.png%2522%250A++++++++%257D%250A++++++%257D%252C%250A++++++%2522features%2522%253A+%250A++++++%255B%250A++++++++%257B%250A++++++++++%2522type%2522%253A+%2522TEXT_DETECTION%2522%250A++++++++%257D%250A++++++%255D%250A++++%257D%250A++%255D%250A%257D&) then press the `Execute without OAuth` button, and you get results that look like this:

```
{
 "responses": [
  {
   "textAnnotations": [
    {
     "locale": "en",
     "description": "How to\nInsert Text\nText Boxes in\nGoogle Docs\nBox\nControlAltAchieve.com @ericcurts\n",
     "boundingPoly": {
      "vertices": [
       {
        "x": 128,
        "y": 20
       },
       {
        "x": 909,
        "y": 20
       },
       {
        "x": 909,
        "y": 502
       },
       {
        "x": 128,
        "y": 502
       }
      ]
     }
    },
... And so on for many a page ...
```